# How to use css gradient using a variable in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, css-gradients

I want to use the following css property in the Navlink component. In CSS file , the property can be written as given below which uses `gradient`.

```
.ele {
       background-image:
       linear-gradient(45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), 
       linear-gradient(-45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%),
       linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%),
       linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%);

       background-size:20px 20px;    
       background-position:0 0, 10px 0, 10px -10px, 0px 10px;
}
```

While using in react taking them as a variable `tabStyle` as shown below, I know that:

- `background-size` changes to `backgroundSize`
- `background-image` changes to `backgroundImage`
- `background-position` changes to `backgroundPosition`

but how can we use `linear-gradient`?

NavbarJs Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const NavbarComponent = () => {

let location = useLocation();

let tabStyle = {
   backgroundImage:
   linearGradient('45deg', '#808080 25%', 'transparent 25%'), 
   linearGradient('-45deg', '#808080 25%', 'transparent 25%'),
   linearGradient('45deg', 'transparent 75%', '#808080 75%'),
   linearGradient('-45deg', 'transparent 75%', '#808080 75%');

  }

return (
  <>
    <nav variant="pills" className="navbar" style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid white" }}>
      <ul className="nav nav-pills">
        <li>
          <NavLink style={location.pathname === "/" ? tabStyle:{}} to="/">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink style={location.pathname === "/about" ? tabStyle:{}} to="/about">About</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink style={location.pathname === "/articles-list" ? tabStyle:{}} to="/articles-list">Articles</NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</>
 );
};

export default NavbarComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

no you don't need to use Camelcase syntax for css functions like `linear-gradient` just use a simple string

```js
let tabStyle = {
   backgroundImage:
   "linear-gradient(45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%)",
   "linear-gradient(-45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%)",
   "linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%)",
   "linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%)";
}
```

Comment: This is not working :(

Comment: It is just working when I have single `linear-gradient` line

Answer (score 0):

It should be just `"linear-gradient()"` as a string value of `backgroundImage:`

Comment: It is just working when I have single `linear-gradient` line

Comment: Does it work if you have all the linear-gradients in a single string separated by commas?

Comment: ```let tabStyle = {
   backgroundImage:
   "linear-gradient(45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%)";
}```

Like this?

Or maybe even without the commas and just the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick look, it looks like there is a syntax error with the styles object you are passing in. Try something like

```
export default function App() {
  const styles = {
    background: `
      linear-gradient(45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), 
      linear-gradient(-45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%),
      linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%),
      linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%)
    `
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" style={true ? styles : {}}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Works in my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-edison-nqynx?file=/src/App.js

[image]